# Kibana index pattern not saved

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack, xpack

I have an ELK stack running on the Kubernetes cluster with security enabled. Everything is running fine and I am able to push data to an index. After logging in to Kibana as an admin user, and I to "Discover" it asks me to create an index pattern. So I have some metricbeat data, and I create a pattern and saved it. But when I go back to discover, it is prompting me to create an index pattern again!

I don't find any errors in Kibana/Elastic pods

Really appreciate any pointers

Elastisearch version: 7.10.1

Comment: Are you sure that the time picker is set to a period in which you have data?

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of index patterns ?

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm running it all on docker, default ports, single node. When I click "Kibana > Index Patterns" in the panel, it shows "You have data in Elasticsearch. Now, create an index pattern." I go through the process successfuly; my pattern shows " Your index pattern matches 1 source." I advance all the way to Create the index pattern, and get a screen showing all fields (112). Then, if I click "Kibana > Index Patterns" again, I get the same message "You have data in Elasticsearch.
Now, create an index pattern."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What finally worked for me was destroy and recreate Kibana. After recreating kibana i was able to see all the index patterns i have been trying to save

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Recreating the Kibana Pod seemed to have solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Stop container, and restart, and everything worked properly.